# Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'object[]' during map and reduce in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a list of file names in an array. My goal is to read all the files in the array and convert them to json from string.
This is the signature of the readAFile() API.

```
readAFile(fileName: string, encoding: 'utf-8'): any {
  return fs.readFileSync(filename, {encoding: encoding});
}
```

Now, I have an array containing absolute path to all the files that is to be read `files = ['/path/to/file1', '/path/to/file2', '/path/to/file3']`.
I have another function that maps each file name in this list to the `readAFile()` and reads them and converts them to JSON like this:

```
readAllFiles(files: string[]): object[] {
  **return** files.map((aFile) => {
    return readAFile(aFile); // this api's return type is 'any'
  })
  .reduce((listOfJson, dataOfOneFile) => {
     const jsonData = JSON.parse(dataOfOneFile);
     listOfJson.push(jsonData);
     return listOfJson;
  }, []);
}
```

I want to include the file name as well, here's what i added

```
  files.map((aFile) => {
    const mappedData = {};  // Added this
    mappedData['data'] = readAFile(aFile); // the data now goes into this object
    mappedData['inputFile'] = aFile;
    return mappedData;    <------ ERROR: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'object[]'.
  })
```

I figured that the simple fix to this problem is `return [mappedData];`. I am not sure i understand this correctly. Could some one help me understand why is this an error? Also, any alternative suggestions are welcome.
EDIT 1: added missing return statement in readAllFiles(). typo.

Comment: `readAllFiles` is missing a `return`.

Comment: @cartant: sorry for the typo. my code has return. I have made the changes to my post. I still get the same error

Comment: You should leverage type inference and use `files.map(f => ({data: readAFile(f), inputFile: f ))` As @artem hints at, the return type of `readAllFiles` is superior when inferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `return` expression in your `readAllFiles` is so complex it's hard to see where the error is coming from. Let's split it into intermediate parts: here it's in the form suitable for viewing and compiling in [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) (I had to provide fake `fs` declaration because node types are not available there, and also had to fix `encoding` parameter for `readAFile`):

```
declare var fs: { readFileSync(filename: string, { encoding: string }) };

function readAFile(fileName: string, encoding: string): any {
  return fs.readFileSync(fileName, {encoding: encoding});
}

function readAllFiles(files: string[]): object[] {
  const mf = files.map((aFile) => {
    const mappedData = {};  // Added this
    mappedData['data'] = readAFile(aFile, 'utf8'); // the data now goes into this object
    mappedData['inputFile'] = aFile;
    return mappedData; 
  });

  const rf = mf.reduce((listOfJson, dataOfOneFile) => {
     const jsonData = JSON.parse(dataOfOneFile); // <-- first error is here 
              // JSON.Parse expects string, but dataOfOneFile is an object now

     listOfJson.push(jsonData); // <-- and the real error is here
                // Property 'push' does not exist on type '{}'.
     return listOfJson;
  }, []);

  return rf;
}
```

Why does it say `Property 'push' does not exist on type '{}'`, when the last parameter of reduce is given as empty array -  `[]`, surely it should have a `push` method?

You see, `reduce` is [declared as overloaded function with 2 variants](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L1073):

```
reduce(callbackfn: (previousValue: T, currentValue: T, currentIndex: number, array: ReadonlyArray<T>) => T,
        initialValue?: T): T;
```

and

```
reduce<U>(callbackfn: (previousValue: U, currentValue: T, currentIndex: number, array: ReadonlyArray<T>) => U,
         initialValue: U): U;
```

The first one has `initalValue` **with the same type as array element**, `T`, and for whatever reason it's the declaration chosen by compiler when no types are explicitly given, so in your code the type of `initialValue` and `previousValue` is the same as the type of array element - `{}`.

Why does not it complain when you pass empty array `[]`, when it expects empty object `{}`?

Because empty array is compatible with it - arrays are objects in javascript, empty object has no properties at all, so any array can be assigned to it.

How to make `reduce` to return different type?

You can tell the compiler that you want the second variant of reduce - the one with different `initialValue` type. If you want it to be `object[]`, you can provide it as explicit generic parameter for reduce:

```
 const rf = mf.reduce<object[]>((listOfJson, dataOfOneFile) => {
```

But why are you using reduce, when you are not really reducing a list to a single value? If you need to make another list from a list, a single `map` will do just fine:

```
function readAllFiles(files: string[]) {
  return files.map((aFile) => {
    return {
      data: JSON.parse(readAFile(aFile, 'utf8')),
      inputFile: aFile
    }
  });
}
```

the type is inferred as

```
function readAllFiles(files: string[]): { data: any; inputFile: string; }[]
```

Comment: thank you this helped! after breaking it down, i manipulated it separately and it works now! used the first variant of reduce()